# Elastic Beanstalk with Docker deployment failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my application with docker and elastic beanstalk. My Dockerrun.aws.json file looks like

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "jvans/maven_weekly",
    "Update": "true"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
    "ContainerPort": "5000"
  }],
  "Volumes": [
    {
      "HostDirectory": "/Users/jamesvanneman/Code/maven_weekly/maven_weekly",
      "ContainerDirectory": "/maven_weekly"
  }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

I created this application with `eb create` and when I run `eb deploy` I get

```
Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit 

unexpectedly on Mon Sep 21 01:15:12 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

In `var/log/eb-activity.log` I see the following errors:

```
  Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Mon Sep 21 01:08:52 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details. (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: 83ea9b7f9a069eeb8351fef7aaedb8374f7dfe300a5e0aaeba0fe17600583175
[2015-09-21T01:08:52.205Z] INFO  [2246]  - [Application deployment/StartupStage1/AppDeployEnactHook/00run.sh] : Activity failed.
```

So it seems like there's a problem with a startup script. If i ssh into the container and try to run it manually I don't really get any extra help from error messages.

`eb ssh`

`sudo /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact/00run.sh`

```
Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Mon Sep 21 01:34:52 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details.
Msg: Docker container quit unexpectedly after launch: Docker container quit unexpectedly on Mon Sep 21 01:34:52 UTC 2015:. Check snapshot logs for details.
```

Are snapshot logs something different than what's in `var/log/eb-activity.log`? Any Idea what is going on/how I can debug this further?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Docker dumps are stored in the host box at `/var/log/eb-docker/containers/`.
Go there and you'll find the docker startup crash log that should indicate the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 8):

You want to look at

```
/var/log/eb-docker/containers/eb-current-app/unexpected-quit.log
```

in the bundle downloaded by `eb logs --all` or using `eb ssh`. This log file will have the stdout and stderr of your application before it crashed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `unexpected-quit.log` was empty and the other log files in `/var/log/` didn't help.

So I found out why the container was crashing by manually running the image on the server.

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ nano Dockerfile # or clone the entire project
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ sudo docker build -t test .
[ec2-user@ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx ~]$ sudo docker run --rm test
Exception in thread "main" …
```

I fixed that exception, redeployed a new version and now the container starts without issues.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I did an `eb ssh` to connect into the ec2 instance and looked at my server logs. It was an application error. Nothing to do with AWS. Fixed it. Tried again and it's working!